# Sharing Y-axis in a matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, subplot

I have been trying to create a `matplotlib subplot (1 x 3)` with **horizontal bar plots on either side of a lineplot**.

It looks like this:
[image]

The `code` for generating the above plot -

```
u_list = [2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 4, 0, 0]
n_list = [0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 3, 1, 1, 0, 6]
arr_ = list(np.arange(10, 11, 0.1))

data_ = pd.DataFrame({
    'points': list(np.arange(0, 10, 1)),
    'value': [10.4, 10.5, 10.3, 10.7, 10.9, 10.5, 10.6, 10.3, 10.2, 10.4][::-1]
})

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(20, 8))

ax1 = plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
sns.barplot(u_list, arr_, orient="h", ax=ax1)

ax2 = plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
x = data_['points'].tolist()
y = data_['value'].tolist()
ax2.plot(x, y)
ax2.set_yticks(arr_)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

ax3 = plt.subplot(1, 3, 3, sharey=ax1, sharex=ax1)
sns.barplot(n_list, arr_, orient="h", ax=ax3)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

**Edit**

> How do I share the `y-axis` of the `central line plot` with the other `horizontal bar` plots?

Comment: The problem is that `seaborn` changes the tick-labels but not the ticks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set the limits of all y-axes to the same range, set the ticks in all axes and than set the ticks/tick-labels of all but the most left axis to be empty. Here is what I mean:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

u_list = [2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 4, 0, 0]
n_list = [0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 3, 1, 1, 0, 6]
arr_ = list(np.arange(10, 11, 0.1))
x = list(np.arange(0, 10, 1))
y = [10.4, 10.5, 10.3, 10.7, 10.9, 10.5, 10.6, 10.3, 10.2, 10.4]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(20, 8))

axs[0].barh(arr_,u_list,height=0.1)
axs[0].invert_yaxis()

axs[1].plot(x, y)
axs[1].invert_yaxis()

axs[2].barh(arr_,n_list,height=0.1)
axs[2].invert_yaxis()


for i in range(1,len(axs)):
    axs[i].set_ylim( axs[0].get_ylim() ) # align axes
    axs[i].set_yticks([]) # set ticks to be empty (no ticks, no tick-labels)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

This is a *minimal* example and for the sake of conciseness, I refrained from mixing matplotlib and searborn. Since seaborn uses matplotlib under the hood, you can reproduce the same output there (but with nicer bars).

Comment: The `y_ticks` disappear but the `lineplot` does not share the `y-axis` with the other two bar plots. This does not help.

Comment: @shikharmishra good point, I forgot that seaborn behaves differently than pure matplotlib. It uses standard ticks and changes the labels rather than plotting the bars at the given ticks (with the labels). I changed the code, which now your suit your needs =)

Comment: I think I must stop using seaborn. Exactly what I needed. Thanks